# How to solve: Android license status unknown and also Android sdkmanager tool not found?

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools

Tried everything i had found(github issues, SO questions) . Also tried to re-install Android SDK(29) from Android Studio.

1. flutter doctor

   ```
   C:\Users\Zheny>flutter doctor
   Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
   [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.693], locale ru-RU)
   [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
       X Android license status unknown.
         Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
         See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed      instructions.
   [√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
   [!] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
       X Flutter extension not installed; install from
         https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
   [!] Connected device
       ! No devices available
   ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
   ```
2. flutter doctor --android-licenses

   ```
   Android sdkmanager tool not found 
   (C:\Users\Zheny\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
   Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
   visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
   ```
3. flutter doctor -v

   ```
   C:\Users\Zheny>flutter doctor -v
   [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.693], locale ru-RU)
   • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\Flutter SDK\flutter
   • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (2 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
   • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
   • Dart version 2.7.0

   [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
   • Android SDK at C:\Users\Zheny\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
   • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
   • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
   • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Zheny\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
   • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
   X Android license status unknown.
     Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
     See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

   [√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
   • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
   • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
   • Dart plugin version 192.7761
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

   [!] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
   • VS Code at C:\Users\Zheny\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
   X Flutter extension not installed; install from
     https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

   [!] Connected device
   ! No devices available

   ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
   ```
4. Screens of my PATH's and folders
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

How can i sovle this problem?

Comment: Same issue in Linux. Android Studio 3.6 in Ubuntu 18.04
```
$ flutter doctor 
...
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Android sdkmanager tool not found
....

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps

- Open the Android Studio SDK Manager
- In the Android SDK tab, uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages
- Check Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)

[image]

Source:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#install-android-studio

Comment: I didn't have installed **Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)**.

Answer (score 2):

download https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools and extract in

C:\Users\Zheny\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk folder

and set path like this

C:\Users\Zheny\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin

restart power-shell or command prompt
and execute 
flutter doctor --android-licenses

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps:

1. open SDK Manager
2. go to SDK tools
3. Delete the "Android SDK Tools" from SDK Manager
4. first deselect the "Hide Obsolete Packages" and then select "Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)", install it.
5. run flutter doctor --android-licenses and select y for the prompts.

run flutter doctor and everything will be fine!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your install paths,
your System Variables should have:
ANDROID_HOME C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\

your Path should have:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
C:\src\flutter\bin

Then run "flutter doctor" from command prompt (without the quotation marks).

If same error occur, open Android Studio, go to Settings and navigate to "Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK", then at the top of the window and to the right of Android SDK Location, click on Edit, and from the window that opens, update your current SDK Manager and install the latest API if not already installed; once everything is updated or installed in this windows, close the Android Studio and close the command prompt.

Open a new command prompt and run "flutter doctor" again (without the quotation marks). Follow the software instructions to accept all Android Licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

```
1. Open the Android Studio SDK Manager
2. Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)
```

Install this one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this in flutter_console

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and then then

```
flutter doctor
```

My issue is solved by this