# Android license status unknown l Flutter doctor

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I just installed Android studio and followed flutter setup. When i run `flutter doctor` i'm facing the issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256569/android-sdkmanager-tool-not-found). Problem is that i can't foud Android SDK Tools (obsolete) in the list.

In addition, if i run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` i'm getting

> Android sdkmanager tool not found
>   (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
>   Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK

What can i do?

Comment: You can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60799492/3176899

Comment: Already tried, there's not "android sdk tools (obsolete)" in the list

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Android Studio 3.6.1?